# Add column headings to nomentbl

Tags: sectioning, nomenclature

I would like to add a header ("Symbol", "Description", "Unit") to my nomenclature using `nomentbl`. I have read through several posts on the internet and it seems possible, but I have to change the `.ist` file. Can anyone provide me further help?

Thank you in advance! 
Cheers

The preamble looks like this:

```
\usepackage{nomentbl}
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\newcommand{\abk}{\nomenclature} 
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenklatur} 
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{% 
   \ifx#1A\relax 
     \large \bfseries Abkürzungsverzeichnis 
   \fi 
   \ifx#1P\relax 
     \large \bfseries Physikalische Größen 
   \fi 
   } 
\makenomenclature
```

And I add new symbols using this code:

```
\abk[A]{$m$}{mass}{kg}{} 
\abk[P]{$\alpha$}{acceleration}{m/s$^2$}{}
```

EDIT:
Thanks to Mr. Swann, my initial problem has been solved. But now I'm interested in further customization of my nomenclature. Therefore I attached two files, which show the current nomenclature and a nomenclature which I would like to achieve. Is it possible to make the changes I marked in the file of my current nomenclature?

Current:
[image: current nomenclature]
Goal:

[image: goal nomenclature]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! It is best to collect code snippets in to one small compilable document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Well, I don't really have a problem while compiling it. I just don't know how to do it. So there isn't any "not-working-code" :)

Comment: The request is to help those who wish to work on the problem and future visitors, so one can just download a single piece of code and try to compile that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so obvious.  The first idea, as you hint at, is to modify the `.ist` file, to print these headers, but that does not play well with the `\nomgroup`'s: using a standard `longtable` set-up would mean the three column headings come before the `\nomgroup` headings, which does not look good.

Instead you can add code to the latex file writing the `\nomgroup` command as

```
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
   \ifx#1A\relax
   \large \bfseries Abkürzungsverzeichnis
   \fi
   \ifx#1P\relax
   \large \bfseries Physikalische Größen
   \fi
   \hfill \endgroup \\ \\
   Symbol&Beschreibung&Einheit \begingroup
   }
```

The change to your current version is to add the final two lines of code.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[german]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{nomentbl}

\newcommand{\abk}{\nomenclature}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenklatur}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
   \ifx#1A\relax
   \large \bfseries Abkürzungsverzeichnis
   \fi
   \ifx#1P\relax
   \large \bfseries Physikalische Größen
   \fi
   \hfill \endgroup \\ \\
   Symbol&Beschreibung&Einheit \begingroup
   }
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

Etwas\dots

\nomenclature[A]{$m$}{mass}{kg}{}
\nomenclature[P]{$\alpha$}{acceleration}{m/s$^2$}{}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

This relies on the details of what is written in the `.nls` file at each `\nomgroup`. There you find

```
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\nomgroup{A}} \\
\nopagebreak\\*[\parskip]
```

The new `\nomgroup` code above closes the the `\multicolumn` group after providing the section formatting, inserts some new lines and the three column headings, and finally reopens a group to match the remaining `}` at the end of the original `\multicolumn` invocation.  This means that what is effectively called is

```
\multicolumn{3}{l}{ \large \bfseries Title \hfill } \\ \\
Symbol&Bechreibung&Einheit {} \\
\nopagebreak\\*[\parskip]
```

providing a title row followed by the three column headings.  The `\hfill` prevents unwanted wide spacing in titles consisting of several words.

You may wish to add `\nopagebreak` at the insert line breaks, if you find the page breaking is bad.

*Update* In response to your comment, if you wish to have different headings in subsection that you can essentially moving the heading code inside the conditional statements, but you next extra macros.  Here is a reasonably modular approach:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[german]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{nomentbl}

\newcommand{\abk}{\nomenclature}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenklatur}
\newcommand{\nomgrouphead}[1]{\large\bfseries #1 \hfill}
\newcommand{\nomgroupX}[2]{\nomgrouphead{#1}\endgroup  \\ \\
#2 \begingroup}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
   \ifx#1A\relax
   \nomgroupX{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}{Symbol&Beschreibung&Einheit}
   \fi
   \ifx#1P\relax
   \nomgroupX{Physikalische Größen}{Buchstaben&Namen&Einheit}
   \fi
   }
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

Etwas\dots

\nomenclature[A]{$m$}{mass}{kg}{}
\nomenclature[P]{$\alpha$}{acceleration}{m/s$^2$}{}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Andrew, unfortunately it doesn't work with my code. Since the answer is too long for a comment on you answer, I added another answer to my question with my code.

Comment: The problem was the package "colortbl", without it, everything works perfect! Thank you!
One more thing, do you know if it is possible to change the header within the groups? For example:
List of Abbreviations: -> Abbreviation -> Description
and in the List of Symbols: -> Symbol -> Unit -> Description

Comment: Thank you Andrew, works perfect! I edited my first post in this topic, because I am looking for further customizations (edit vspace, leftflush instead of centered etc.). Maybe you can take a look on it as well?

Comment: I think it would be better to ask a separate question with these new requirements.  Some of the spacing you are seeing is due to other packages you are loading, not currently specified, you need provide further details.

Comment: ok, I will do so! :)